# Merging a list of strings and a list of lists

Tags: python, list

This maybe a duplicate but I couldn't find a specific answer.

I also found one answer in composing this question but would like to know if there is a better option or one which works without knowing which item is a list of strings.

My question:

```
la=['a', 'b', 'c']
lb=[['d','e'], ['f','g'], ['i','j']]
```

I would like:

```
[['a','d','e'], ['b','f','g'], ['c','i','j']]
```

I discovered the following works specifically for my example;

```
la=['a', 'b', 'c']
lb=[['d','e'], ['f','g'], ['i','j']]
[ [x] + y for x,y in zip(la, lb)]
[['a', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'f', 'g'], ['c', 'i', 'j']]
```

It works because I make the string list into a list before concatenating and avoids the ***TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects***

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: what is more elegant than a natural, 1-line solution?

Comment: @JohnColeman agree, doesn't get much better than this

Comment: @hSchroedl The solution is so natural that I wrote it up and submitted it as an answer within 30 seconds of reading the first part of the question but then deleted my answer right away when I saw that OP already had that solution, which made me wonder about the point of the question.

Comment: what is the question do you think is a duplicate?

Comment: what happens if the item is not a list of string?

Comment: Yes I see your points.  Just that I struggled to create my solution until I changed x+y in the comprehension to [x]+y.  So I wondered if there was a way to do similar where it would work even without knowing one was a list of strings?  i.e. flatten each list item and merge in one go even when one is a normal list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.column_stack`:

```
>>> la=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lb=[['d','e'], ['f','g'], ['i','j']]
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.column_stack((la,lb))
array([['a', 'd', 'e'],
       ['b', 'f', 'g'],
       ['c', 'i', 'j']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Why down vote? is there any problem with my answer? I would be happy to hear about my mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an expression I can't think of anything better than using zip as above. If you want to explicitly insert elements elements from la into elements of lb at their heads, I'd do

```
for i in range( len(la) ):
    lb[i].insert(0, la[i])
```

which avoids having to know what zip is or does. Maybe also first check:

```
if len(la) != len(lb) : raise IndexError, "List lengths differ"
```

without that it'll "work" when lb is longer than la. BTW This isn't exactly the same wrt corner cases / duck typing. Seems safer to use insert, which method should exist only for a list-like object, than "+".

Also, purely personally, I'd write the above on one line

```
for i in range( len(la) ): lb[i].insert(0, la[i])
```